# Javascript lastChild call returns sibling, when using empty element tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following piece of Javascript:

```
//Clear out container
var container = document.getElementById("buy");
while (container.lastChild)
{
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
}
```

and further down, the piece of HTML on which it operates:

```
<div id="buy" class="itemGroup" />

<canvas id="drawArea" width="200" height="200">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

However, the Javascript code removes the canvas, unless the buy div uses start and end tags i.e.

```
<div id="buy" class="itemGroup">
</div>
```

Why is this?  I thought the two, from an XML point of view, are equivalent?  Using Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m on Windows 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<div>` is not a self-closing tag :)

Comment: You're missing a quote in the class... so essentially, the next element is still inside the div tag, instead of the element

Comment: browsers are sometimes forgiving in the way you use tags, since you used an invalid div markup it automatically converted it, and in doing so moved everything after it into the div (till it finds a closing div tag i believe), if you look in your developer console and look at the elements tab you should see this

Comment: Sorry Philip - fixed that - was typing into the window directly.  Turns out <div> is not a self-closing tag, you learn something every day.  Many thanks!

Comment: In HTML5 `<div />` just means `<div>`.. checkout this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/352672

Answer (score 0):

This is not a more complete answer than the comments already given per se, but I just can't add a comment to your post. Anyway, there are some tags which are not self closing and 'div' is one of them - which actually makes sense if you think about it. Semantically speaking, why are you making a 'division' if there's nothing in it?

Another tricky one is 'script'. Even if you are linking to an external script file in your page, you cannot use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js" />
```

this just doesn't work. Another one is 'textarea'. This renders any html after it useless!

```
<textarea cols="5" rows="5" />
```

Take a look at some other ones: http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html